# Sending emails from AuraEnabled method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, singleemailmessage

I'm trying to trigger an email sending from a lightning component. Right now I'm just trying to send a basic test email with the following code:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static String serverSendOrderEmail(String cartId) {

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        message.toAddresses = new String[] { 'myemail@gmail.com' };
        message.optOutPolicy = 'FILTER';
        message.subject = 'Subject Test Message';
        message.plainTextBody = 'This is the message body.';
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);

        if (results[0].success) {
            return 'The email was sent successfully.';
        } else {
            return 'The email failed to send: ' + results[0].errors[0].message;
        }
    }
```

All I get is a non-descript **"An internal server error has occurred"** when trying to get this to run. I've tried this as well as some examples directly from the Salesforce documentation and get the same result. I've run in to things like the Cookie class that don't work with lightning components and am hoping that this isn't the case with emails as well. If there's any information that someone might have or a direction to point me in that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your lightning component code?

Comment: Something else might go wrong, try wrapping your method in try catch to check if there are any errors?